# The point of using Java access modifiers?

Tags: java, javabeans, access-modifiers

I have used Java for quite some time. I know what the four types of Java access modifiers and I have experience in using them in real world applications.

However, I have a question about the access modifiers: **What's the point of using different access modifiers?**

In other words, what is the reasons behind for having access modifiers in the design of Java language.

Is it just to prevent other developers from accessing certain class/properties *accidentally*? Or, is it because we want to somehow show the "intention" of the use/scope of classes/properties in the application?

I see that many experienced developers dealing with access modifiers, not because they have strong reasons to use them, but mainly because the langauge has such feature and it's the *best practice*. They choose different access modifiers mainly by the "convention" they have stuck in their mind.

I think many consultants and experts these days got stuck with the idea of using access modifiers because they never ask themselves "how about not using them"? Don't get me wrong. I am not saying they are useless and we shouldn't use them. I am just asking if it is mainly designed for improving developer's convention of coding. There are many other programming languages that do not support access modifiers, but that doesn't make them bad languages and they can still be used in corporate applications too.

I was trained that classes and properties should be declared as *private* as possible if you don't want other classes to mess with them.

One of my colleagues gave me this explanation before - "If we want to share our libraries to third parties, we don't want them to access certain classes/properties. We want to keep these classes/properties secret. " In my mind, I thought, "Really? Is that really the reason? I think either you or me, one of us has got the idea very wrong."

Let's say I have downloaded an open source library, and *IF* I really want to access some of the private classes/properties, I can just go into the library code and change their access modifiers, right? Even if I don't want to/cannot touch the code, I can, at runtime, use reflection to change the access modifiers. I know it's hackish, but that does what I want.

I've also heard from someone saying it's for data enccapsulation.... but I just thought - Java classes are designed to have such encapsulation feature already, I don't need access modifers to do that.

Sometimes, when I am reading API docs of a third party library, I see pages about private classes. If the original developer chose to use the **private** access modifier, then I guess he/she has the intention of keeping access of those classes away from us, right? Those classes are probably designed for logic in background and need not to be exposed to us. Then why bother having API docs on private classes?

=====

The other thing related to Java access modifiers which I don't understand, is the design of Java Beans. Why do we keep all the fields in a Bean private and then access them via public getters and setters? Why shouldn't I just have public fields? It's a waste of time and error-prone to write/generate and to manage all these getters/setters sometimes. For example, what's the difference between the two below?

```
myBean.setX("foo");
String bar = myBean.getX();
```

compared to

```
myBean.x = "foo";
String bar = myBean.x;
```

My colleague told me that using getters and setters are safer and may prevent any accidental access. I just don't see how a sensible developer will access them accidentally.

I have read from some books before, suggesting you can add logic code and other data modifiying code inside the getters and setters, so when a getter/setter is being accessed, it's more than just field accessing. However, I truely believe this is a bad practice. the point of Java Beans is about data encapulation. Logic should be done somewhere else, not inside Java Beans, and especially not inside setters and getters.

Comment: To, err, modify the access. The rest of this is just a rant.

Comment: @EJP Seriously? You did not get the point of my question, did you? Or you just did not bother finish readinig the whole thing? I am really asking about the reasons of existence of access modifiers, not what they are use for.

Comment: Seriously. I didn't read the whole thing: who would? The fact is that decades of experience show privacy of methods and data to be valuable, your opinions notwithstanding.

Comment: At least 4 decades (Simula 67 ...)

Answer (score 4):

> Is it just to prevent other developers from accessing certain class/properties accidentally? Or, is it because we want to somehow show the "intention" of the use/scope of classes/properties in the application?

Basically ... both of these things.

Your colleague said:

> If we want to share our libraries to third parties, we don't want them to access certain classes/properties. We want to keep these classes/properties secret.

You are right.  That is not the reason.  The `private` modifier is not effective for that purpose, for a variety of reasons.

If you want to keep parts of the code / state secret: 1) don't share the source code, 2) obfuscate the compiled code, 3) if you really care about it, don't share the code **at all** ... because even obfuscated code can be reverse engineered, with enough effort.

---

The rest of your question seems to be a statement of your opinions on access modifiers, and I will not respond to that.  (This is a Q&A site.  If you want to start a discussion, this is the wrong place to do it!)

Answer (score 1):

One word: encapsulation. If you want to drive a car, you don't need to know the details of how the engine is working, you just need to know how to use it. In fact, the vast majority of drivers know relatively little about car engines.

When you use a library, you're much more concerned with how to use it than with the implementation details. In fact, that's one of the main points of object-oriented development to begin with.

I disagree with the stuff your colleague was saying about secrecy. You can just get information about private methods through reflection anyway, so it's not like you can maintain the secret if someone else was motivated to access it.

What it *does* do is statically prevent you from calling a method that you're not supposed to without making a significant effort to do so.

By analogy, it's not really that I *can't* bypass the steering wheel and ignition and whatnot and go directly act on my car's engine, it's that I'd have to go out of my way to do it. The interface protects me from accidentally taking actions on the engine that might be harmful to it.

With regards to the documentation issue, if the public documentation of an API has details of private methods in it, it's bad documentation. That information doesn't belong in public-facing documentation, plain and simple. Ever. At all. For any reason whatsoever. Including those details in public-facing documentation summons tainted souls to the realm of the living.

Comment: You get +1for bringing up documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer despite the obvious trollery. Every choice a programmer makes in software creation is to lock the code down to do what it is supposed to do, *and nothing else*. (If that isn't what you're doing, you're not a programmer, you're just a coder.) "Best practices" are called that for a reason; in practice they're the best at accomplishing that goal.

The practices of public interface (not the Java keyword, the CS concept) and private implementation are best for keeping code bug free and stably useful. When the contract of a type is clear, consistent, and durable, that type is more useful and less costly than when, for example, there is excess coupling to implementation details.

For example, the public contract of a `HashMap` is expressed in the `interface` (keyword this time) `Map`. Nothing in the interface reveals how hash collisions are stored. Recently the implementation changed from a linked list to judicious use of a red-black tree if conditions warrant. Had the linked list been public, that change would have broken every program that uses `HashMap`. Because collision management is encapsulated, instead of breaking, all those programs got a small performance improvement.

I strongly suggest that you study object-oriented programming to understand concepts such as encapsulation, the Law of Demeter, coding to the interface, and all the other best practices that are, in practice, best.

Answer (score 0):

Public fields tend to link you to a particular implementation and limit your flexibility in changing your code.